# Java code with CloudWatch or XRAY or IOT analytics?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-xray

New to AWS, I am writing a code for IDE in java so its desktop based application. I am trying to log some events in the application and I want it to be logged on cloud server. So, basically trying different services of aws. Tried for cloud watch, but it works on only aws applications. Trying to get more data on xray and IOT analytics. But no success. Can anybody suggest a proper solution.
Or is there a way that I can log the events somewhere on server and read through cloud watch.

Comment: CloudWatch Logs works with any application, not just AWS applications.

Answer (score 0):

[Cloudwatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_GettingStarted.html) is the AWS native logging service. There are several ways to send data to it.

- You can [install an agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) on your cloud/on-prem server and send logs to it.
- Using the [AWS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html) to send logs directly (you should probably use the [SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/))

For either of those options, you will need to ensure you enable your application to access AWS. This is usually done by creating a user and role, and generating an access and secret key. There's a lot of nuance to doing this part correctly, so take your time.

The other tools you mentioned provide different services. XRAY is an Application Performance Monitoring tool that will let you get trace data and other insights into how your application runs. You usually correlate log data to this to help with debugging. IOT Analytics is specific to Internet Of Things / embedded devices and probably not a good fit for your Java app.